# AttributeError at /addtowatchlist/5: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'listings'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Within my app, I'm allowing any given user to add an auction listing to their watch list, but no matter what I have tried, it does not seem to work and I keep getting the error in the title. I am simply trying to access the user thats making the request and adding the listing to their watchlist and redirecting them to the main page.

**views.py**

```
from .models import *

def add_to_watchlist(request, listing_id):
    
    listing = Listing.objects.get(id=listing_id)
    # Retrieving the user watchlist (where it always fails)
    watchlist = PersonalWatchList.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    

    # Fails here too
    if (watchlist.listings.all() == None) or (listing not in watchlist.listings.all()):
        watchlist.listings.add(listing)
        watchlist.save()
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Listing is already in your Watchlist.")
        return redirect(reverse('index'))

    messages.success(request, "Listing added to your Watchlist.")
    return redirect(reverse('index'))
```

**models.py**

```
class PersonalWatchList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    listings = models.ManyToManyField(Listing, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Watchlist for {self.user}"
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("create", views.createListing, name="create"),
    path("view/<str:listing_title>", views.view, name="view"),
    path("addtowatchlist/<int:listing_id>", views.add_to_watchlist, name="add_to_watchlist")
]
```

**Section of template used to add listing to watchlist**

```
<div class="listing-actions">
<a href= {% url 'view' listing.title %} class="btn btn-primary view-button">View</a>
<!--TODO: Make watchlist-->
<a href={% url 'add_to_watchlist' listing.id %} class="btn btn-primary add-to-watchlist-button">Watchlist</a>
</div>
```

I have tried changing my logic around using try and except, but it still results in a very similar error. In my urls.py I have tried changing the path names to avoid them from overlapping, as the "view" and "add_*to_*watchlist" were similar before, but that change still has not worked. Before, in

> watchlist = PersonalWatchList.objects.filter(user=request.user)

I used get() instead, and that wasn't working either. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**
When I add listings to a given users watchlist through django admin, that works just fine, which I really don't understand how, but through the server itself it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I essentially had to change up my logic, as I came to understand that the reason this error was being thrown was because the User did not exist yet in the PersonalWatchList Model. Here is the updated workaround.

**views.py updated**

```
def add_to_watchlist(request, listing_id):
    user = request.user

    # Getting the listing that was clicked
    listing = Listing.objects.get(id=listing_id)

    # Retrieving the user watchlist (if it exists)
    try:
        watchlist_exists = PersonalWatchList.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except:
        watchlist_exists = None

    # If there isn't one for this user, make one
    if watchlist_exists == None:
        PersonalWatchList.objects.create(user=user)

    # Access that watchlist
    watchlist = PersonalWatchList.objects.get(user=user)

    # Comparing the listings already present in their watchlist to the one that was hit
    if (listing not in watchlist.listings.all()):
        watchlist.listings.add(listing)
        watchlist.save()
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Listing is already in your Watchlist.")
        return redirect(reverse('index'))

    messages.success(request, f"'{listing}' added to your Watchlist.")
    return redirect(reverse('index'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve an individual user's watchlist, use get instead of filter:

```
watchlist = PersonalWatchList.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Using the filter() method is returning a QuerySet (Multiple objects) as opposed to the single unique one you want.

The other issue is in your model definition. To use the default user class as a foreign key, you need to use

turning this:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

into this:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Try this and comment your results.

Comment: I added in the changes, and just to confirm I import settings from 'django.conf' right? It still doesn't seem to work for users that don't have any listings in their watchlist. However, when I add a listing to someones watchlist who I manually added through django admin, it works. It's failing at this line again 'watchlist = PersonalWatchList.objects.get(user=request.user)'

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? The commandline where you ran python manage.py runserver will have a stack trace of the error

Comment: I managed to get it to work! The issue was in my logic with the user not being registered in the model in the first place, so I had to create the user in the model then add to their listings, thanks for your help!